# Trying to get script to not run if a cell is not blank

Tags: excel, vba

The code is relatively straight forward. if I click on a cell in L8:L98, and the cell is blank, then the cell has "T" put into it and the other relevant cells are emptied.

```
If Intersect(Target, Range("C7:C98")) Is Nothing And Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98"))
        .Value = "T"
        .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
End With
```

My problem is that if a cell on the same row in the C column has data in it, I want the if statement to return false and skip it. I also tried the code with `Intersect(target.offset(, -9)...` and without the intersect. Neither have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VBA doesn't short-circuit best to break you code into two IF tests (so the second condition isn't run needlessly):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Cells(Target.Row, "C")) = 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98"))
                .Value = "T"
                'presume you set Col elswehere?
                .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
            End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Intersect test whether the cell in which you click is in the range, Unless you are clicking on a cell in C and a cell in L at the same time then you will never satisfy the If.

So let's test whether the cell in Column C in the same row is blank or not.

```
If Range("C" & Target.Row)="" And Not Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Intersect(Target, Range("L7:L98"))
        .Value = "T"
        .Offset(, 1).Resize(, Col).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: For some reason, this works in the opposite manner. I was able to modify the string by putting in `If Not Range("C" & Target.Row) <>""` and that solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Instead just change the `<>` to `=` and forget the `Not` @Thelnternet